# Aggregate nodes and relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'd like to perform a check on a property that exists on both nodes and relationships in my DB. Is there any way to aggregate them all as *entity* and then perform the check on *entity* instead of performing three separate checks?

**What I currently have is:**

```
MATCH (n1)-[r]-(n2) WHERE (myConditions) 
WITH n1, r, n2 
WHERE n1.property=1 AND r.property=1 AND n2.property=1 
RETURN *
```

**What I'm looking for is something like:**

```
MATCH (n1)-[r]-(n2) WHERE (myConditions) 
WITH n1, r, n2 AS entity
WHERE entity.property=1 
RETURN *
```

**Important note:** There are queries with more than 2 nodes and more than one relationships. I would like to aggregate all graph entities and then perform a single check.

By the way, if "aggregation" is not the right term for this case, please feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use predicates like `all()`, `any()`, `none()` etc. on all nodes and relationships in your path. You still have to check for nodes and relationships separately.

```
MATCH path=(n1)-[r]-(n2)
WHERE (myConditions)
WITH path   
WHERE all(n in nodes(path) WHERE n.property = 1)
AND all(r in relationships(path) WHERE r.property = 1)
RETURN path
```